# Effective way to read file and parse each line

Tags: java, nio, java-io

I have a text file of next format: each line starts with a string which is followed by sequence of numbers. Each line has unknown length (unknown amount of numbers, amount from 0 to 1000).

```
string_1 3 90 12 0 3
string_2 49 0 12 94 13 8 38 1 95 3
.......
string_n 9 43
```

Afterwards I must handle each line with `handleLine` method which accept two arguments: string name and numbers set (*see code below*).

*How to read the file and handle each line with `handleLine` efficiently?*

My workaround:

1. Read file line by line with java8 streams `Files.lines`. *Is it blocking?*
2. Split each line with regexp
3. Convert each line into header string and set of numbers

I think it's pretty uneffective due 2nd and 3rd steps. 1st step mean that java convert file bytes to string first and then in 2nd and 3rd steps I convert them back to `String`/`Set<Integer>`. *Does that influence performance a lot? If yes - how to do better?*

```
public handleFile(String filePath) {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        stream.forEach(this::indexLine);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void handleLine(String line) {
    List<String> resultList = this.parse(line);
    String string_i = resultList.remove(0);
    Set<Integer> numbers = resultList.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    handleLine(string_i, numbers); // Here is te final computation which must to be done only with string_i & numbers arguments
}

private List<String> parse(String str) {
    List<String> output = new LinkedList<String>();
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+|[a-z]+|[A-Z]+").matcher(str);
    while (match.find()) {
        output.add(match.group());
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Just as suggestion, maybe move Pattern.compile outside this method, I think you do not need compile the same pattern for each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first question, it depends on how you reference the `Stream`. `Streams` are inherently lazy, and don't do work if you're not going to use it. For example, the call to `Files.lines` doesn't actually read the file until you add a terminal operation on the `Stream`.

From the java doc:

> Read all lines from a file as a Stream. Unlike readAllLines, this method does not read all lines into a List, but instead populates lazily as the stream is consumed

The `forEach(Consumer<T>)` call is a terminal operation, and, at that point, the lines of the file are read one by one and passed to your `indexLine` method.

Regarding your other comments, you don't really have a question here. What are you trying to measure/minmize? Just because something is multiple steps doesn't inherently make it have poor performance. Even if you created a wizbang oneliner to convert from the `File` bytes directly to your `String` & `Set`, you probably just did the intermediate mapping anonymously, or you've called something that will cause the compiler to do that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code to parse line into name and numbers

```
stream.forEach(line -> {
    String[] split = line.split("\\b"); //split with blank seperator
    Set<String> numbers = IntStream.range(1, split.length)
                                .mapToObj(index -> split[index])
                                .filter(str -> str.matches("\\d+")) //filter numbers
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    handleLine(split[0], numbers);
});
```

Or another way

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> collect = Pattern.compile("\\b")
                                            .splitAsStream(line)
                                            .filter(str -> !str.matches("\\b"))
                                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str -> str.matches("\\d+")));
handleLine(collect.get(Boolean.FALSE).get(0), collect.get(Boolean.TRUE));
```

Answer (score 1):

I set out to test several ways to go about this problem and measure the performance as best I could under noted conditions. Here's what I tested and how I tested it, along with the accompanying results:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class App {

    public static void method1(String testFile) {
        List<Integer> nums = null;
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Paths.get(testFile))) {
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                if (s.hasNextInt())
                    nums.add(s.nextInt());
                else {
                    nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    String pre = s.next();
                    // handleLine( s.next() ... nums ... );
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void method2(String testFile) {
        List<Integer> nums = null;
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile));
                Scanner s = new Scanner(in)) {
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                if (s.hasNextInt())
                    nums.add(s.nextInt());
                else {
                    nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    String pre = s.next();
                    // handleLine( s.next() ... nums ... );
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void method3(String testFile) {
        List<Integer> nums = null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = line.split(" ");
                nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i)
                    nums.add(Integer.valueOf(arr[i]));
                // handleLine( ... );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void method3_1(String testFile) {
        List<Integer> nums = null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = line.split(" ");
                nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i)
                    nums.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[i]));
                // handleLine( ... );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void method4(String testFile) {
        List<Integer> nums = null;
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(testFile));
            for (String s : lines) {
                String[] arr = s.split(" ");
                nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i)
                    nums.add(Integer.valueOf(arr[i]));
                // handleLine( ... );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void method4_1(String testFile) {
        List<Integer> nums = null;
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(testFile));
            for (String s : lines) {
                String[] arr = s.split(" ");
                nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i)
                    nums.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[i]));
                // handleLine( ... );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void method5(String testFile) {
        List<Integer> nums = null;
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(testFile))) {
            List<String> lines = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
            for (String s : lines) {
                String[] arr = s.split(" ");
                nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i)
                    nums.add(Integer.valueOf(arr[i]));
                // handleLine( ... );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void method5_1(String testFile) {
        List<Integer> nums = null;
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(testFile))) {
            List<String> lines = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
            for (String s : lines) {
                String[] arr = s.split(" ");
                nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i)
                    nums.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[i]));
                // handleLine( ... );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void method6(String testFile) {
        List<Integer> nums = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(testFile))) {
            stream.forEach(line -> {
                String[] split = line.split("\\b"); // split with blank seperator
                Set<String> numbers = IntStream.range(1, split.length)
                        .mapToObj(index -> split[index])
                        .filter(str -> str.matches("\\d+")) // filter numbers
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
                numbers.forEach((k) -> nums.add(Integer.parseInt(k)));
                // handleLine( ... );
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        args = new String[] { "C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\test.txt" };

        Random r = new Random();

        System.out.println("warming up a little...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
            int x = r.nextInt();
        }

        long s1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            method1(args[0]);
        long e1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long s2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            method2(args[0]);
        long e2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long s3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            method3(args[0]);
        long e3 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long s3_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            method3_1(args[0]);
        long e3_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long s4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            method4(args[0]);
        long e4 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long s4_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            method4_1(args[0]);
        long e4_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long s5 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            method5(args[0]);
        long e5 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long s5_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            method5_1(args[0]);
        long e5_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long s6 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            method6(args[0]);
        long e6 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("method 1 = " + (e1 - s1) + " ms");
        System.out.println("method 2 = " + (e2 - s2) + " ms");
        System.out.println("method 3 = " + (e3 - s3) + " ms");
        System.out.println("method 3_1 = " + (e3_1 - s3_1) + " ms");
        System.out.println("method 4 = " + (e4 - s4) + " ms");
        System.out.println("method 4_1 = " + (e4_1 - s4_1) + " ms");
        System.out.println("method 5 = " + (e5 - s5) + " ms");
        System.out.println("method 5_1 = " + (e5_1 - s5_1) + " ms");
        System.out.println("method 6 = " + (e6 - s6) + " ms");
    }
}
```

- Used with java.version = 1.8.0_101 ([Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/index.html))
- x64 OS/processor

Result output:

```
warming up a little...
method 1 = 1103 ms
method 2 = 872 ms
method 3 = 440 ms
method 3_1 = 418 ms
method 4 = 413 ms
method 4_1 = 376 ms
method 5 = 439 ms
method 5_1 = 384 ms
method 6 = 646 ms
```

To my understanding, the best approach out of the sample I tested was using `Files.readAllLines`, `s.split(" ")`, and `Integer.parseInt`. Those three combinations produced the apparently fastest *again, out of the sample I created and tested with* At least maybe you'd change to the `Integer.parseInt` to help somewhat.

Note I used sources to help gain some sought after approaches and applied them to this problem/example. E.g. [this blog post](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/12/java-sequential-io-performance.html), [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/randomaccessfile.html), and this awesome dude [@Peter-Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey). Also, ***further improvements can always be made***!

Also, the test.txt file:

```
my_name 15 00 29 101 1234
cool_id 11 00 01 10 010101
longer_id_name 1234
dynamic_er 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 123 1456 15689 555555555
```

(note: performance may greatly vary depending on file size!)